# Make element fit it's entire parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an advanced administration panel, and I'm playing the part of editing items, I like it when I clicked to edit an item he would fill the entire space of its parent, however I have no idea how to make the element back to its original position with animation, any idea how to do this? I tried this so far:

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvGONp

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="single-item">
        <div class="title">home</div>
        <a class="edit" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="single-item">
        <div class="title">Gallery</div>
        <a class="edit" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="single-item">
        <div class="title">Contact</div>
        <a class="edit" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#container{
    & > .single-item{
        position: relative;
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 15px;
        z-index: 1;

        & > .edit{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #000;
            top: 15px;
            right: 15px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        &.active{
            z-index: 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#container").on("click", ".edit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this);
    var elParent = el.closest(".single-item");

    var curElTop = elParent.position().top;
    var curElLeft = elParent.position().left;

    elParent.toggleClass("active", function(){
        elParent.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: curElTop,
            left: curElLeft
        }).animate({
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Use CSS3 for your animations, instead of javascript [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) will get you started

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transition will help you create smooth animation for full screen width & height.

But if still for some reason, you want to do it in jQuery, here is the solution :

While clicking second time on the "edit" button, you just have to say :

```
$("<element_reference>").removeAttr("style");
```

It will remove the styles what was applied previously, get back the element to its normal view.

Or you can also change the position from "absolute" to "static", both will give you the same result. [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202749/jquery-can-i-animate-the-positionabsolute-to-positionrelative) for animating position using jQuery.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the easiest way to do things like this is:

1. Put CSS transition properties on the item.
2. Make a new class that you add onto the item when it's clicked, to make it fullscreen. Take off the class when the item is closed.

CSS transitions tend to be faster and smoother.